# How to store result set or jobid of sql query on cloud?

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud, parquet, ibm-cloud-sql-query

I am pushing data from a SQL query on cloud to db2 on cloud, when I am querying data and storing it in my s3 bucket it is saving jobid of that particular query result.

But when I am pushing data into db2 it is not saving any jobid, in fact data has been inserted. I am checking by going again on db2.

But how do I came to know on SQL query that my query has succeeded or not? I want to confirm it when I am running the SQL query on cloud.

My query:

```
select 
    a.col, a.col2, explode (a.col3) company_list
from 
    cos://us-east/akshay-test-bucket1/Receive-2020-03-11/CP-2020-03-11/ STORED AS PARQUET c
into 
    crn:v1:bluemix:public:dashdb-for-transactions:eu-gb:a/2c36cd86085f442b915f0fba63138e0c:61f353e4-6640-4599-b1dd-48ee52ee008d::/schema_name.table_name
```

[image]

Here I am storing data into db2 and SQL query is saying "A preview is only possible for results stored in Cloud Object Storage" as you can see in above screenshot and see my query.

Comment: I would imange that you would get an error message if your query did not succeed.

Comment: Maybe edit your question of an example of a query that fails where you don't get an error message back.

Comment: yes, i am getting error and succeed message but at that time when i am storing my result into my s3 bucket

`SELECT * FROM cos://us-east/akshay-test-bucket1/po/part1.parquet
STORED AS PARQUET 
INTO cos://us-east/akshay-test-bucket1/query-result/ STORED AS JSON`

Comment: my job id getting stored here

**cos://us-east/akshay-test-bucket1/query-result/jobid=7b291731-fe7a-4**

Comment: Please see my question i have added image and sql query

Comment: @PaulVernon I am not sure I understand the question. The SQL Jon does show whether it finished and with what outcome (completed vs. failed) in the job list to the left, no matter whether the target is object storage or Db2.

Comment: yes @TorstenSteinbach correct, but can we write result set to be store somewhere in query..?


`select a.col,a.col2, explode (a.col3)company_list from cos://us-east/akshay-test-bucket1/Receive-2020-03-11/CP-2020-03-11/ STORED AS PARQUET c into crn:v1:bluemix:public:dashdb-for-transactions:eu-gb:a/2c36cd86085f442b915f0fba63138e0c:61f353e4-6640-4599-b1dd-48ee52ee008d::/schema_name.table_name`

Comment: @PaulVernon A SQL job will always write the result set to one defined target location. In your case above it's the table in the Db2 instance. If you use a different INTO clause with a COS URI instead, then you'll get it on COS. Of course you could also simply just chain two SQL jobs, the first one doing your actual SQL with an INTO clause to COS and then a second one that does SELECT * from that just written data on COS and writes it INTO your Db2.